# Что такое фрагмент понятным языком?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Перечитал всю документацию по этому делу. Но как-то все равно не понял, что такое фрагменты. Есть для самого себя идея. Возьмем приложение ВК на андроиде. Получается, что все там просиходит на одной активности, а все остальное(кроме наверно после нажатия на пользователя) - фрагменты? Или как?

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=RU):

> Фрагмент (класс Fragment) представляет поведение или часть
>   пользовательского интерфейса в операции (класс Activity). Разработчик
>   может объединить несколько фрагментов в одну операцию для построения
>   многопанельного пользовательского интерфейса и повторного
>   использования фрагмента в нескольких операциях. Фрагмент можно
>   рассматривать как модульную часть операции. Такая часть имеет свой
>   жизненный цикл и самостоятельно обрабатывает события ввода. Кроме
>   того, ее можно добавить или удалить непосредственно во время
>   выполнения операции. Это нечто вроде вложенной операции, которую можно
>   многократно использовать в различных операциях.

А теперь простым и человеческим языком (скажу сразу что я дальше буду приводить примеры из своей практики и мое мнение субъективно, как и любое мнение здесь может быть подвержено критике - короче не очень сильно кидайте в меня помидоры вдруг я что-то не так скажу :) ) - фрагмент это как активность на минималках. Что это значит? Вот к примеру, спросите вы что круче фрагмент или активность - это довольно распространенный вопрос потому что у всех кто начинает разрабатывать приложение нет практики. На мой взгляд круче активность. Почему? Потому что в активности может быть размещен контейнер который будет заменять фрагменты. Да, сейчас многие скажут что и в фрагменте можно разместить контейнер и там крутить фрагменты (такого я честно говоря не встречал), но опять таки это мое мнение. Фрагмент намного легче чем активность, но он так же может не иметь некоторых методов которые имеет активность. Он легче для устройства и поэтому его советуют использовать в приложение в которых много разветвлений. Фрагменты используются для создания пересоздаваемых экранов - если у вас будет обновляться содержимое экрана, то лучше использовать фрагмент. Вернемся к нашим баранам, а именно ВК - приложение довольно популярное и я думаю все его видели. Я думаю что там используются фрагменты, так как они будут легче обрабатываться большим кол-вом устройств а значит покроют большее кол-во юзеров. Лично я использую как активности так и фрагменты. Вот [ссылка_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/why-fragments-and-when-to-use-fragments-instead-of-activities), [ссылка_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity) и [ссылка_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500438/activities-vs-fragment-implementation) авось поможет.

P.S. Смею напомнить что я написал мое личное мнение, так как человек попросил объяснить ему понятным языком, а для меня эта версия понятна. Поэтому просьба, все у кого есть другое мнение пишите свои замечания в комментариях, чтобы я отредактировал свой ответ, ведь **вместе мы сила** :)

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, Ваш вопрос, наводит на мысль, что все-таки очень мало прочитали и мало искали информацию.  Фрагменты нужны чтобы переиспользовать отдельные части экрана. В основном они были нацелены на работу с планшетами.   Например, есть экран, на нем всего несколько элеметов. На телефоне он выглядит нормально, а на планшете получается, что большая часть экрана пустая. Следовательно на планшете можно показать сразу два связных (по смыслу) экрана. Две активности показывать одновременно мы не можем, поэтому если каждый экран реализовать в отдельном фрагменте, мы сможем их объединить в одной активности, а для телефона показывать в двух разных активностях.   Даже на телефоне может возникнуть такая ситуация, когда часть экрана с одной активности, нужна и в другой. Чтобы не дублировать код, эту часть экрана помещают в фрагмент.  Но если вы заметили, получается ситуация, что на планшете одна активность содержит два фрагмента, а телефон для каждого фрагмента должен отдельную активность держать. Можно решить этот вопрос тем, что эти два связных экрана будут на телефоне тоже одной активностью, а переход осуществляется с одного фрагмента на другой.     
 То о чем вы говорите, это подход который продвигал гугл, он называется `Single Activity`, появился относительно недавно, его суть в том, что есть одна активность, а всё остальное реализовано на фрагментах. Но это привносит и свои проблемы, они связаны с навигацией по этим фрагметам. Но это уже детали. 
 И конкретно вам рекомендация: достаточно просто понимать, что фрагмент это часть экрана, которую можно разместить в одной активности. Реализуйте примеры с использованием TabLayout и вы увидите, одно из распространенных применений фрагментов. Не стоит много читать, надо брать и писать простые вещи. Много простых вещей.